# How to reconcile record descriptions in single table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large table of data where part number descriptions were not entered consistently, now I need to figure out a way to reconcile them without using an update statement for each one, here is an example:

```
Part number Description
abcd1       red lamp
abcd1       red lamp w/ plug
abcd2       blue lamp
abcd2       blue lamp w/ plug
abcd3       green lamp
abcd3       green lamp w/ plug
```

How can I take the first description and insert it into all the subsequent records with the same part number? Actually it doesn't have to be the first so long as they can all be grouped into a single record. The records are sales orders of sorts, there is a date column which is why there are multiple records with the same part number. Thanks!

Comment: Are there any additional columns that help determine which description is "first"?  I'm guessing you ordered them that way in the example, but some sort of order number or key would help.

Comment: Unless you have some criteria to accurately and repeatedly select the same 'first' description, you are not going to be able to do this.  How are you defining the 'right' description in a generic way?

Comment: Is the desired result to have a new row for part number "abcd1" with the description "red lamp red lamp w/ plug"?

Comment: Perhaps editing the question to include the desired results table would help.

Comment: How come you are able to have different descriptions for the same partnumber ? Looks like bad table design to me. There should only be one description for each partnumber it looks like you are missing an entire table in your design

Comment: It's actually not imperative to use the first description I just thought that was the most logical, as long as they can all be grouped into a single record.

Comment: *as long as they can all be grouped into a single record*  --  Then why bother with the description at all?  Just aggregate on the part number?

Comment: Your problem is that your SalesOrder table is badly designed. There should be a table `Parts`that looks like `PartID int, Partnumber varchar(), Description varchar(), ...`and in your SalesOrder you should have just one field to link to a part, a field called PartID. This way you never have this problem again. Read up on `Normalization` because this design will keep giving problems

Comment: There is no such thing as a "first" description in a table, unless another column specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a date or sequential id, you can use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             first_value(description) over (partition by partnumber order by ?) as first_description
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set description = first_description
    where description <> first_description;
```

However, you should really be focused on fixing the data model.  You should have a `parts` table, with one row per part and a description that is stored in exactly one place.  That would be the correct way to structure the data.

If descriptive information about the parts can change over time, then you make this a type-2 dimension, with an effective and end date.